# Javascript get date 30 days ago

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I am trying to populate two date input fields, one with today's date and one with the date 30 days ago(last month).

I am getting an error in my console: `priordate.getDate is not a function`

Here is my code, not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
//today's date

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;//January is 0, so always add + 1
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd};
if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm};
today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

//30 days ago

var beforedate = new Date();
var priordate = new Date().setDate(beforedate.getDate()-30);
var dd2 = priordate.getDate();
var mm2 = priordate.getMonth()+1;//January is 0, so always add + 1
var yyyy2 = priordate.getFullYear();
if(dd2<10){dd2='0'+dd2};
if(mm2<10){mm2='0'+mm2};
var datefrommonthago = yyyy2+'-'+mm2+'-'+dd2;

// Set inputs with the date variables:

$("#fromdate").val(datefrommonthago);
$("#todate").val(today);
```

Comment: Did you try using [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/) or is that not an option?

Comment: I am using phonegap with the intention of making this an app, so if possible I would like to avoid external libraries.

Comment: The return value of `setDate()` is not a Date, so you need to split this line: `var priordate = new Date().setDate(beforedate.getDate()-30);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll instead want to use:

```
var priordate = new Date(new Date().setDate(beforedate.getDate()-30));
```

if you want it on one line. By using:

```
new Date().setDate(beforedate.getDate()-30);
```

you're **returning the time since epoch** (a number, not a date) and assigning it to `priordate`, but it's not a `Date` anymore and so does not have the `getDate` function.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `setDate()` [returns a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate), not a `Date` Object.

In any I case I'd strongly recommend using `momentjs` or `date-fns` as the internal `Date` object in JavaScript is broken in all kind of ways. See this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVuor-VAWTI

Comment: I was under the impression that only using javascript was possible when developing with cordova/phonegap. I'll definitely check that video and might consider using moment.js. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
var priordate = new Date().setDate(beforedate.getDate()-30);
```

to this:

```
var priordate = new Date();
priordate.setDate(beforedate.getDate()-30);
```

Comment: Aha! I see where I went wrong. Thank you so much, I understand better now :)